# Find - relations xxx not found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to return and entity including its relation but I am getting an error saying relation xxx not found. I am using the repository pattern.

```
@Entity({ name: 'person' })
export class PersonEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: 'number' })
    statusId: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => StatusEntity, status => status.id)
    status: StatusEntity;
}

@Entity({ name: 'statuses' })
export class StatusEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 256 })
    name: string;
}
```

I am using postgres and I have a foreign key declared:

```
"public"."person" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_person_statusid" FOREIGN KEY ("statusId") REFERENCES "public"."statuses"("id")
```

In my service:

```
public async getAll(): Promise<PersonEntity[]> {
  return await this.personRepository.find({ relations: ['statuses'] });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
@Entity({ name: 'person' })
export class PersonEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: 'number' })
    statusId: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => StatusEntity)
    @JoinTable()
    status: StatusEntity;
}

@Entity({ name: 'status' })
export class StatusEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 256 })
    name: string;
}
```

**Note that** I have changed StatusEntity name from `statuses` to `status`.

Comment: Thanks but no, a person can have only one status. For example, dead or alive, not both. Statuses is a lookup table. As a note, Statuses will never care who is in its status. We will never search, for example, who is alive, in my use case.

Comment: If your use case is like that then I will change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you delete the foreign key you created manually, and then update your entity like below and try?

```
@Entity({ name: 'person' })
export class PersonEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ type: 'number' })
    statusId: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => StatusEntity)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'statusId })
    status: StatusEntity;
}
```